# How is the heat lost in a peltier distributed?

Tags: heat, peltier, loss

I'm looking at peltier elements to heat my project. I seem to find that most are about 5% efficient, but how is the 95% turned into heat distributed?

Does the cold side get 47.5% and the warm side get 52.5% of the energy, or is it more complex depending on the difference between the temperatures? I'm really surprised this hasn't b een asked before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Peltier device is not a marvellous means of heating unless you also value the ability to cool.

A Peltier cooler will transfer ALL electrical heat energy to the hot side PLUS any energy that is "extracted from" the cold side. So, if it is 5% efficient and you input 100 Watts of electrical energy you will get 5 Watts of cooling and 5 + 100 = 105 Watts of heating. While this is more efficient than using a resistive heater it is much more complex and costly per Watt than using resistive heating.